# How to open context menu without long press using javascript in iPhone safari?

Tags: javascript, iphone, contextmenu

Is there a way to do something? :-)

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Long press me!</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // do something to open context menu of anchor element
</script>
```

Comment: @Hwihum Welcome to Stack-over Flow ,please! share your code what you have tried so far to achieve this.so you will get more help from community else this is not a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a javascript on a [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a) you have

`- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script`

```
Parameters
script
The script to run.
Return Value
The result of running script or nil if it fails.
```

> Discussion
>       JavaScript execution time is limited to 10 seconds for each top-level entry point. If your script executes for more than 10
>   seconds, the web view stops executing the script. This is likely to
>   occur at a random place in your code, so unintended consequences may
>   result. This limit is imposed because JavaScript execution may cause
>   the main thread to block, so when scripts are running, the user is not
>   able to interact with the webpage.
>
> JavaScript allocations are also limited to 10 MB. The web view raises
>   an exception if you exceed this limit on the total memory allocation
>   for JavaScript.